# How to change numpy array into grayscale opencv image

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

How can I change numpy array into grayscale opencv image in python?
After some processing I got an array with following atributes: max value is: 0.99999999988,
min value is 8.269656407e-08 and type is: `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. I can show it as an image using `cv2.imshow()` function, but I can't pass it into `cv2.AdaptiveTreshold()` function because it has wrong type:

```
error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::adaptiveThreshold
```

How can I convert this np.array to correct format?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As the assertion states, [`adaptiveThreshold()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold) requires a single-channeled 8-bit image.

Assuming your floating-point image ranges from 0 to 1, which appears to be the case, you can convert the image by multiplying by 255 and casting to `np.uint8`:

```
float_img = np.random.random((4,4))
im = np.array(float_img * 255, dtype = np.uint8)
threshed = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 0)
```

Answer (score 13):

This one worked for me:

```
uint_img = np.array(float_arr*255).astype('uint8')

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(uint_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Answer (score 2):

I need to convert closed image(morphological closing) to binary, and after checking @Aurelius solution, This one work for me better than mentioned solution.

[Python cv2.CV_8UC1() Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89304/cv2.CV_8UC1)

```
mask_gray = cv2.normalize(src=mask_gray, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
```